# Yii2 composer returns an error in installation

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

AM using ubuntu linux in my development

I was installing yii2 advanced template via

```
composer create-project nenad/yii2-advanced-template advanced
```

Which starts the installation upto the point when the vendor directories are being installed and it fails with the error

After some research i found out that i need to instal global asset plugin via

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"
```

But now am getting an error of

```
Changed current directory to /home/myusername/.composer


  [ErrorException]                                                             
 file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I understand its a permission issue and i have

```
  sudo chomd 0777 -R /var/www/html/yii2/advanced
```

but this havent solved the file_put_content error

I have tried

```
   sudo chmod 0777 -R  /home/myusername/.composer
```

but this also fails

What else do i need to do

Answer (score 1):

Using `777` as permission mask is a bad idea. I'd recommend to use `chown` command instead.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.composer
```

This will make composer directory owned by your user and you can use `755` for directories and `644` for files.

To make it clear, what problem composer exactly stumbled upon, try running require command with `-vvv` option. This allows you to run composer in full verbose mode and get debug information.

```
composer -vvv global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"
```

Look into `~/composer` folder and doublecheck file permissions and owner with `ls -al`